# How to return a string in http in ASP.NET MVC 5 controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm refactoring a website using an external service for a form submission, and once they send me the form data, they expect a string of in http response to let them know I've received their POST.

This was what's there previously, when the website was in web forms/aspx.

```
 Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
 Response.Output.Write("OK");
 Response.Output.Flush();
 Response.Output.Close();
```

So I tried this first in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //...get the form data...

    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

But this didn't seem to work. Then I tried:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //...get the form data...

    Response.StatusCode = 200;
    Response.StatusDescription = "OK";

    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK, "OK");
}
```

And it still didn't work. I don't know if they get the 200 and didn't get the "OK" string?

EDIT: By didn't work, I meant that the external service didn't receive my string of "OK".

Comment: If you want to return a string you can do return Content("OK");

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: @BeanFrog My bad, I've edited to add the explanation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple as:

```
return Content("OK", "text/plain");
```